# Access 2007 - accdb; options in setting up a reliable multi-user environment across multiple servers?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2007, multi-user, ms-access

I am having trouble sorting through all the information / various options in regards to Access 2007 used in a multi-user environment.   Here is a brief description of my current situation. At work there is the "Business LAN" which I can log on and use to monitor two other servers via remote desktop.  The business LAN is strictly controlled by our IT department and no one is permitted to install any software or drivers without their consent. I do have administrative privileges on both servers though.

The two servers that I log on to using RD are used for essentially the same task, which is to monitor and control the heat to different process lines. Each server runs a different program to accomplish this task but both programs use SQL Server as a back end.

I created two access databases (one on each server because they are currently behind seperate firewalls)  in order to query information from the backend SQL side of these programs and combine it with relative information I have compiled in tables in order to add more detail to the data the programs are collecting.  My program is still in the debug stage but ultimately this information can then be accessed by field techs / maintenance in order to make their job easier. Maintenance staff can also add even more information based on the status of repairs etc....Last, I have created reports which can be run by Managers / Engineers who are looking for an overall status of their area.

Both access db's are split so that the back ends are seperate from the forms, queries, etc...  I use an ODBC data source to import a link to SQL. I am using vba for user authentication, user logging record updates, and user / group access control. Everything works the way I intended except the fact I everyone who logs on the server will be trying to run the same copy of the front end.  For example, I had a co-worker log on to the server via RD to test the program and I logged on from my desk. After logging in I could see the forms he had open. Access was already running. Without being able to install access locally (or even runtime, due to IT restrictions) on to each individuals workstation, I'm not sure what approach to take to resolve this.

Additional info, Server 1
One of the servers is considered to be the "master server" in which a number of client stations "slave servers" all communicate with. The only way to access folders on themaster server is log on to the client station and run RD.

Server 2 
This server is considered to be the "historian". It communicates with a terminal server in which users log on using RD and run applications which use SQL backend which resides on the historian. I have been able to set up shares so that certain folders are visible on the historian from the terminal server.

Can anyone tell me what my best option is?

Thanks in advance.

CTN

Answer (score 1):

It's really crazy the way some IT departments do everything possible to make it hard to do your job well.

You allude to users logging on via Terminal Server. If so, perhaps you can store the front ends in the user profiles of their Terminal Server logons? This assumes they're not just using the two default admininstrative Terminal Server logons, of course.

The other thing that's not clear to me is why you need a back end at all in Access/Jet/ACE -- why not just link via ODBC to the SQL Server and use that data directly? The only reason to have an independent Jet/ACE file with data tables in it in that scenario is if there is data you're storing for your Access application that is not stored in the SQL Server. You might also have temp tables (e.g., for staging complicated reports, etc.), but those should be in a temp database on a per-user basis, not in a shared back end.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion how to implement what David Fenton wrote: write a simple batch script which copies your frontend from the installation path to %TEMP% (the temporary folder of the current user session) and runs the frontend from there. Something along the lines of

```
 rem make sure current directory is where the script is
 cd /d %~d0%~p0
 rem assume frontend.mdb is in the same folder as the script
 copy /y frontend.mdb %temp%
 start %temp%\frontend.mdb
```

Tell your users not to run the frontend directly, only via the batch script, then everyone should get his own copy of the frontend. Or, give your frontend a different suffix in the installation path and rename it to "frontend.mdb" when copying to %temp%.

Comment: Thank-you Doc and @David-W-Fenton for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: Thank-you Doc and @David-W-Fenton for taking the time to answer my question. Yes my back end contains a lot of useful data for prioritizing alarms that the programs do not provide. Will probaly upload my tables in to SQL at some point. Users access the servers using a comon group login that does not provide administrative access. The number of maintenance staff in addition to contractors who maintain these systems leave individual user accounts an option I don't have. I will definately try using the batch file to create copies of the front end in a temp directory.  Thanks again.

Comment: If I may be allowed a plug for my utility another solution to ensuring frotn ends are updated on a timely basis is the Auto FE Updater at www.autofeupdater.com.  It also solves a lot of other problems including initial distribution and ensuring users only use the utility to start their front end.